# "CoreData: error: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault"

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

This is a part if code when error happens:

```
class func randomWord() -> TBWord {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(TBAppSettings.wordsForCurrentGame.count)))
    let word = TBAppSettings.wordsForCurrentGame[randomIndex]

    TBAppSettings.wordsForCurrentGame.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)

    MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock { context in

        let word = TBWord.findWordWithIdentifier(word.identifier, inContext: context) //here error happens
        word?.used = true
    }

    return word
}
```

How can I workaround this? I know about other questions about this problem, but they are not enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

(Besides the fact that MagicalRecord is a big misunderstanding of how to use Core Data properly...)

Have you tried to run you code with `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` as a launch argument? This smells like a threading problem.